# How to Force a Unique Rule To Ignore A Specific User in Laravel 4?

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

On my set-password view, I want to allow user to edit their own user name and email.

In my controller, I force my validation to ignore the validation on the user with the same activation code.

I still get the error message.I know, I am missing a step, I not sure how to fix this.

Can you give me a quick tip or point out what I missed ?

I've tried, and here is what I come up with.

**Code**

```
public function postSetPassword(){

        $user = User::where('code','=', Input::get('code'))->firstOrFail();
        $code = $user->code;
        $validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), array(

            'password'          =>'required|min:6',
            'password_again'    =>'required|same:password',
            'logo_path'         =>'max:255',

            'username'  =>'required|unique:users,username,'. $code,
            'email'     =>'required|email|unique:users,email,'. $code,

          ... more ...
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's probably many ways to do this but one that comes to my mind is this. Just don't validate the username or email if the user hasn't changed it.

```
$user = User::where('code','=', Input::get('code'))->firstOrFail();
$validationRules = array(
    'password'          =>'required|min:6',
    'password_again'    =>'required|same:password',
    'logo_path'         =>'max:255'
);

if($user->email != Input::get('email')){
    $validationRules['email'] = 'required|email|unique:users,email';
}
if($user->username != Input::get('username')){
    $validationRules['username'] = 'required|unique:users,username';    
}

$validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), $validationRules);
```